# How to preserve dateclass on for loop

Tags: r, class, object

I was wondering if there is a way to preserve the *Date* class when using a for loop.

The following code demonstrate my concern:

```
temp <- structure(c(16565, 16593, 16607, 16719, 16775, 16782, 16866, 
16915, 17048, 17083, 17104, 17118, 17265), class = c("IDate", 
"Date"))

for( n in temp){message(n);print(n)}
```

Also, it is just a quirk but I would appreciate if anyone could explain me if there is any reason why the for loop replace the class for a *numeric* one, as it gave a little bit of fear using other classes besides numerics as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the documentation of `for` says *vector* it is saying that it will get stripped of the class.

> seq
>   An expression evaluating to a vector (including a list and an expression) or to 
>   a pairlist or NULL. A factor value will be coerced to a character vector.

You can use:

```
for(n in as.list(temp)) { message(n); print(n) }
```